# How to upload/share video on Facebook ?

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook-graph-api

I am making a test app through that I want to post video on facebook. I am using latest sdk of facebook. But I  am not able to post it on facebook.

My code is as below.

```
NSDictionary *parameters = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:videoData forKey:@"CareAppDemo.mov"];

FBRequest *request = [FBRequest requestWithGraphPath:@"me/videos" parameters:parameters HTTPMethod:@"POST"];

[request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                NSLog(@"result: %@, error: %@", result, error);
            }];
```

Please help me to post video on facebook via my app.

Comment: See the image and download from there. you have only set facebook appid in it.

Answer (score 5):

You need to download FacebookSDK first 
and then add following framework into your project

> ```
> FacebookSDK.framework, FBSDKLoginKit.framework, FBSDKShareKit.framework,
> Bolts.framework,FBSDKCoreKit.framework
> ```

import them,
and write followin code

```
if(![FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken])
    {
        FBSDKLoginManager *login1 = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc]init];

        [login1 logInWithPublishPermissions:@[@"publish_actions"] handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {

            FBSDKShareVideo *video = [[FBSDKShareVideo alloc] init];

            video.videoURL = videoAssetURL;
            FBSDKShareVideoContent *content = [[FBSDKShareVideoContent alloc] init];
            content.video = video;

            [FBSDKShareDialog showFromViewController:self withContent:content delegate:nil];




        }];
    }
    else {
        FBSDKShareVideo *video = [[FBSDKShareVideo alloc] init];
        video.videoURL = videoAssetURL;
        FBSDKShareVideoContent *content = [[FBSDKShareVideoContent alloc] init];
        content.video = video;

        [FBSDKShareDialog showFromViewController:self withContent:content delegate:nil];




    }
```

The video URL videoURL must be an asset URL. You can get a video asset URL e.g. from UIImagePickerController.

or for recording video you can take as follow

```
ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
[library writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:[NSURL URLWithString:[[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Library/Caches"] stringByAppendingFormat:@"/current.mov"]] completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error)
 {

     videoAssetURL =assetURL;

 }];
```

for more detail you can use https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/ios

Comment: This Works. But not exist way for add title and description to video.

Comment: yes there is no way to add  title and description because of ,see section 2.3  https://developers.facebook.com/policy. 
But we can give one another option to user before post. copy description text  in clipboard(using UIPasteboard) and show alert to user like "Comments have been copied to your clipboard to paste with your post." before posting video.

Answer (score 4):

Successfully tested On **[FaceBook SDK 3.14.1](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/)**

**Recommendation:** 3 properties in .plist file

set FacebookAppID,FacebookDisplayName,
URL types->Item 0->URL Schemes   set to facebookappId prefix with `fb` **[See](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZAXQ.png)**

```
-(void)shareOnFaceBook
{
    //sample_video.mov is the name of file
    NSString *filePathOfVideo = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sample_video" ofType:@"mov"];

    NSLog(@"Path  Of Video is %@", filePathOfVideo);
    NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePathOfVideo];
    //you can use dataWithContentsOfURL if you have a Url of video file
    //NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:shareURL];
    //NSLog(@"data is :%@",videoData);
    NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               videoData, @"video.mov",
                               @"video/quicktime", @"contentType",
                               @"Video name ", @"name",
                               @"description of Video", @"description",
                               nil];

   if (FBSession.activeSession.isOpen)
   {
        [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me/videos"
                                 parameters:params
                                 HTTPMethod:@"POST"
                          completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                              if(!error)
                              {
                                  NSLog(@"RESULT: %@", result);
                                  [self throwAlertWithTitle:@"Success" message:@"Video uploaded"];
                              }
                              else
                              {
                                  NSLog(@"ERROR: %@", error.localizedDescription);
                                  [self throwAlertWithTitle:@"Denied" message:@"Try Again"];
                              }
                          }];
    }
    else
    {
        NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                            @"publish_actions",
                            nil];
        // OPEN Session!
        [FBSession openActiveSessionWithPublishPermissions:permissions defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceEveryone  allowLoginUI:YES
                                     completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                         FBSessionState status,
                                                         NSError *error) {
                                         if (error)
                                         {
                                             NSLog(@"Login fail :%@",error);
                                         }
                                         else if (FB_ISSESSIONOPENWITHSTATE(status))
                                         {
                                             [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me/videos"
                                                                          parameters:params
                                                                          HTTPMethod:@"POST"
                                                                   completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                                                                       if(!error)
                                                                       {
                                                                           [self throwAlertWithTitle:@"Success" message:@"Video uploaded"];

                                                                           NSLog(@"RESULT: %@", result);
                                                                       }
                                                                       else
                                                                       {
                                                                           [self throwAlertWithTitle:@"Denied" message:@"Try Again"];

                                                                           NSLog(@"ERROR: %@", error.localizedDescription);
                                                                       }

                                                                   }];
                                         }
                                     }];
        }
}
```

I GOT Error In first time of App runs:

```
 The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 5.)
```

It happens when facebook is being inited. Next time i open my app, it works fine, its always the first time. Tried everything in app, but it seems to be on the Facebook SDK side.

Few causes for seeing `com.facebook.sdk error 5`:

- Session is is not open. Validate.
- Facebook has detected that you're spamming the system. Change video name.
- Facebook has a defined limit using the SDK. Try a different app.
- Wrong publish permission. Give `publish_actions` a spin.
- many more....

Comment: This works but did you ever figure out how to get around the first time issue? Id liek to fix it if I can.

Comment: when you are not approve your app from Facebook. Then it will give error on first time.
After Approval by Facebook, It's running successfully.

Comment: Awesome thanks for the tip. I actually ended writing a hack to make it work as well by nesting another call after the first one - so if you are testing you don't get the error displayed.

Answer (score 1):

Best Example to upload video on Facebook [Check it](https://github.com/eternalstorms/ESSVideoShare-for-OS-X-Lion)

Download from below link that's only iPhone

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Get the publish permission

```
NSArray* permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                            @"publish_stream", nil];
    [facebook authorize:permissions delegate:self];
    [permissions release];
```

Try this

```
- (void)fbDidLogin {
    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sample" ofType:@"mov"];
    NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   videoData, @"video.mov",
                                   @"video/quicktime", @"contentType",
                                   @"Video Test Title", @"title",
                                   @"Video Test Description", @"description",
                       nil];
    [facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/videos"
                         andParams:params
                     andHttpMethod:@"POST"
                       andDelegate:self];
}
```

Comment: I Used this code. but not worked. I got the error lik this             error: Error Domain=facebookErrDomain Code=10000 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (facebookErrDomain error 10000.)" UserInfo=0x758a250 {error={
    code = 100;
    message = "API calls from the server require an appsecret_proof argument";
    type = GraphMethodException;

Comment: So my guess is that your App Setting for appsecret_proof is enabled, but you are not using the latest version of iOS SDK so the appcesret_proof is not generated.
You might want to check your setting at App Dashboard > Setting > Advanced > Security.

Answer (score 1):

This is the old thread but for all the future readers coming, here is how to do it with the currently latest facebook SDK (`v3.24.0 - September 10th 2015`).

```
- (IBAction)bntShareOnFacebookAction:(id)sender {

    if ([[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken] hasGranted:@"publish_actions"]) {
        [self shareVideoOnFacebook];
    } else {
        FBSDKLoginManager *loginManager = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
        [loginManager logOut];  //very important line for login to work
        [loginManager logInWithPublishPermissions:@[@"publish_actions"]
                handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
                        if(!error) {
                            [self shareVideoOnFacebook];
                        } 
                    }];
    }
}

- (void) shareVideoOnFacebook {

    NSString *videoPath = @"/Documents/.../movie.mov";
    NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:videoPath]];

    NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:3L];

    [params setObject:videoData forKey:@"video_filename.MOV"];
    [params setObject:@"Title for this post." forKey:@"title"];
    [params setObject:@"Description for this post." forKey:@"description"];

    [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"/me/videos" parameters:params HTTPMethod:@"POST"]
     startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
         if (!error) {
             //video posted
         }
     }];
}
```

Comment: Doesn't adding a pre-filled description violate Facebook's policy? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/prefill

Comment: @Matt - fields are hardcoded for demonstration purposes only, to make the code more readable. Feel free to extract that info from user input.

Answer (score 0):

IF you want to Upload/Video sharing you must need to pass the Assets Library URL for the original version of the picked item.

```
URL e.g assets-library://asset/asset.MOV?id=18BC70A0-208A-4F03-A207-7D57C8863425&ext=MOV
```

If you are using

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
```

Then you must need to pass

```
NSURL *url = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];
```

If you using Document Directory Path then first you need to save video into library. You must need to create url link Assets Library URL.

```
[[PHPhotoLibrary sharedPhotoLibrary] performChanges:^{

    [PHAssetChangeRequest creationRequestForAssetFromVideoAtFileURL:videoURL];

} completionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSError * _Nullable error) {

    if (success) {

        // Fetch Last saved video.
        PHFetchOptions *fetchOptions = [[PHFetchOptions alloc] init];
        fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"creationDate" ascending:false]];

        // Get video url.
        PHAsset *fetchResult = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithMediaType:PHAssetMediaTypeVideo options:fetchOptions].firstObject;
        NSString *assetID = [fetchResult.localIdentifier substringToIndex:(fetchResult.localIdentifier.length - 7)];
        NSURL *assetURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"assets-library://asset/asset.MOV?id=%@&ext=MOV", assetID]];

        // Share Video.
        FBSDKShareVideo *video = [[FBSDKShareVideo alloc] init];
        video.videoURL = assetURL;

        FBSDKShareVideoContent *content = [[FBSDKShareVideoContent alloc] init];
        content.video = video;

        FBSDKShareDialog *shareDialog = [[FBSDKShareDialog alloc] init];
        shareDialog.shareContent = content;
        shareDialog.delegate = (id)self;
        shareDialog.fromViewController = self;
        NSError * error = nil;
        BOOL validation = [shareDialog validateWithError:&error];
        if (validation) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [shareDialog show];
            });
        } else {
            NSLog(@"%@", error.localizedDescription);
        }

    }

}];
```