# How to share/post a video on Facebook in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, facebook

I want to share/post video file to facebook via my application.
How to share it?

Tried this one but not working.

```
NSURL *videourl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me/videos"];

NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"me" ofType:@"mov"];
NSURL *pathURL = [[NSURL alloc]initFileURLWithPath:filePath isDirectory:NO];
NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

NSDictionary *params = @{
                        @"title": @"Me being silly",
                        @"description": @"Me testing the video upload to Facebook with the new system."
                        };

SLRequest *uploadRequest = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook
                                              requestMethod:SLRequestMethodPOST
                                                        URL:videourl
                                                 parameters:params];
[uploadRequest addMultipartData:videoData
                       withName:@"source"
                           type:@"video/quicktime"
                       filename:[pathURL absoluteString]];

uploadRequest.account = self.facebookAccount;

[uploadRequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {
    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    if(error){
        NSLog(@"Error %@", error.localizedDescription);
    }else
        NSLog(@"%@", responseString);
}];
```

Comment: Possible Duplicate Please check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21402660/how-to-upload-share-video-on-facebook